# WPF: can't pass System.Int32 as CommandParameter

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, icommand, commandparameter

I have a `Button` with an attached `Command`:

```
<Button Command="{Binding Path=command}">
    <Button.CommandParameter>
        <s:String>1</s:String>
    </Button.CommandParameter>
</Button>
```

where the `command` is:

```
public ICommand command
{
    get { return new DelegateCommand<string>((string str) => MessageBox.Show(str)); }
}
```

So far everything works fine. When I press the button, the `MessageBox` with "1" message is shown.

But when I'm trying to pass a `System.Int32` value as `CommandParameter`, no message is shown:

```
<Button Command="{Binding Path=command}">
    <Button.CommandParameter>
        <s:Int32>1</s:Int32>
    </Button.CommandParameter>
</Button>

public ICommand command
{
    get { return new DelegateCommand<System.Int32>((System.Int32 n) => MessageBox.Show(n.ToString())); 
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Put a break point and see if any error comes or not. Also check for output window in VS for any error.

Comment: @NikhilAgrawal, thank you, Debug output window helped me. It appears that type T for DelegateCommand<T> generic class must be nullable. So I should simply replace `Int32` with `Int32?` in the code behind.